# how save checkbox value with shared preferences?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences

hy everybody, i don't know why my code not save checkbox checked value; if i check checkbox and after i click on another tab and comeback to previous tab, checkbox is not selected...i hope that you find the error in my code!

IDE say me: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at line ".onCreateView(holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);"

why?

thanks in advance!

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

{

  private List<Planet> planetList;
  private Context context;
  ArrayList<Birra> objects;


  public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
      super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
      this.planetList = planetList;
      this.context = context;
  }




    public  class PlanetHolder  {
      public TextView planetName;
      public TextView distView;
      public TextView valuta;
      public CheckBox chkBox;
      public EditText edit;
      public String quantità;



  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {





      View row = convertView;
      PlanetHolder holder = null;
      if (row == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
          row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
          holder = new PlanetHolder();
          holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
          holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
          holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
          holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
          holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
          holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
          row.setTag(holder);
      } else {
          holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
      }
       final Planet p = planetList.get(position);


      final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;
      if(p.isCheckBoxchecked ())
      {
          finalHolder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
      }
      /*SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      boolean mCheckBoxValue = preferences .getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);

      if (mCheckBoxValue) {

          holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
      } else {
          holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
      }*/


      holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                  SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 /* SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                  editor.putBoolean("showActivity", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());
                  editor.commit();*/
                 // boolean value= true;
                  SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences .edit();
                  mEditor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());

                  mEditor.commit();

                  finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                      @Override
                      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                          p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                          SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                          editor.putString("KEY", finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());

                          editor.commit();

                      }
                  });
              } else {
                  finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                  finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

              }

          }
      });
      holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
      holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
      holder.valuta.setText(""+p.getValuta());
      holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
      holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
      holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

          return row;
  }


  ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
      ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
      for (Planet p : planetList) {
          if (p.selected)
              box.add(p);
      }
      return box;
  }


}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      // preferences.getBoolean("showActivity", false);
       //preferences.getString("KEY", null);
    boolean mCheckBoxValue = preferences .getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    if (mCheckBoxValue) {
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
    }





    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        showResult(v);


        }
    });
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

PLANET:

```
class Planet {

    String name;
    int distance;
    String quantità;
    String valuta;
    boolean selected = false;
    boolean mCheckBoxState;


    public Planet(String name, int distance, String valuta) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.valuta = valuta;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getQuantità() {
        return quantità;
    }

    public void setQuantità(String quantità) {
        this.quantità = quantità;
    }
    public String getValuta() {
        return valuta;
    }

    public void setValuta(String valuta) {
        this.valuta = valuta;
    }


    public boolean isCheckBoxchecked () { return mCheckBoxState; }
    private void setCheckBoxCheck(boolean state){ mCheckBoxState = state; }

}
```

Comment: Either `holder` or `holder.chkBox` is null.

Comment: so, where is my mistake?

Comment: i don't know how initialize an object about class PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder

Answer (score 0):

The fragment views will be refreshed each time so better option will be instead of storing it in preferences make use of the item (object) used to create the value
For Ex in adapter carry out this operation
final Planet p = planetList.get(position);

```
  final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;

  //set the check box if its previously checked
  if(p.isCheckBoxchecked)
  {
   finalHolder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
  }


  holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
              finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
              SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MaterialTabs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             /* SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("showActivity", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());
              editor.commit();*/
             // boolean value= true;
              SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = preferences .edit();
              mEditor.putBoolean("CheckBox_Value", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked());
              mEditor.commit();

              finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                  @Override
                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                  //set the item been checked
                  p.setCheckBoxCheck(true);


                  }
              });
          } else {
              finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
              finalHolder.edit.setText(null);

          }

      }
  });
```

Comment: what are you getting in p.isCheckBoxchecked ?? each time you debug and once you set . pl. debug it and check

Comment: when i write "p.", IDE suggest me to write "p.isSelected()"

Comment: because "isCheckBoxchecked" is underline in red by IDE

Comment: pl. write a method in model class with getter method and setter method bascially

Comment: sorry, but i i am not understanding....

Comment: what i must write in method "isCheckBoxchecked"?

Comment: ---------- In your  planet class add 2 methods   ----------                                                                boolean mCheckBoxState;
    private boolean isCheckBoxchecked ()
    {
        return mCheckBoxState;
    }

    private void setCheckBoxCheck(boolean state){
        mCheckBoxState = state;
    }

Comment: doesn't work same...

Comment: you checked if its getting saved and what comes when you retrieve... bascially this should work as you are making change in  your model class . is your model class recreated?? check that once

Comment: now i edit code so you can see ;)

Comment: ok, now you can see...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this library](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper) to reduce complexity with your shared preferences related code. And if your shared preferences determine the state of views being displayed make sure you do relevant checks for stored values in the onCreate methods.